# How to search the field which could contains spaces,- and a concatenated number.?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr6

Hi I have a field with the following schema,

```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords.txt" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" protected="protwords.txt" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I am storing complete pdf documents.

Now suppose I have 4 documents with the following content.

```
1. stackoverflow is a good site.
2. stack-overflow is a good site.
3. stack overflow is a good site.
4. stackoverflow2018 is a good site.
```

Now when I search `stackoverflow` It should return me 1, 
when I search `stack-overflow` it should return me 2.
when I search `stack overflow` it should return me 3.
when I search `stackoverflow2018` it should return me 4.

what should the schema for it the schema not working in this case.
Is there any thing I could specify in the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Word Delimiter Graph Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/filter-descriptions.html#word-delimiter-graph-filter) will split on non-alphanumerics (`-`), case changes, and numbers by default.

> The rules for determining delimiters are determined as follows:
>
> A change in case within a word: "CamelCase" -> "Camel", "Case". This
>   can be disabled by setting splitOnCaseChange="0".
>
> A transition from alpha to numeric characters or vice versa:
>   "Gonzo5000" -> "Gonzo", "5000" "4500XL" -> "4500", "XL". This can be
>   disabled by setting splitOnNumerics="0".
>
> Non-alphanumeric characters (discarded): "hot-spot" -> "hot", "spot"
>
> A trailing "'s" is removed: "O’Reilly’s" -> "O", "Reilly"
>
> Any leading or trailing delimiters are discarded: "--hot-spot--" ->
>   "hot", "spot"

If you don't want that behavior, remove the WordDelimiterFilter from your filter list and add other filters to support the part of the WDF behavior that you need.

Comment: `Non-alphanumeric characters (discarded): "hot-spot" -> "hot", "spot"` Is there any way to discard/disable this behavior ?

Comment: Not everything at once, but you can use the `types` parameter with a file that redefines `-` to be an alphanumeric - `- => ALPHANUM`. See the `types` parameter in the source linked above.